# How do I know what to whitelist to allow my application into the system tray?

Tags: indicator

I know how to whitelist applications so as to allow them into the Unity system tray, but how do I figure out exactly what string I need to whitelist?

The application I'm interested in is [cdemu-tray](http://cdemu-tray.sourceforge.net/), but a general answer would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Enable the system tray icon in your applications
- Run `unity` from a gnome-terminal

You will see something like this in the output:

```
** (compiz:3932): DEBUG: TrayChild Rejected: Opera opera Opera
```

I'm not exactly sure why it's those three in this case, but just adding *opera* or *Opera* to the whitelist works. If you start Unity again, you'll get:

```
** (compiz:4034): DEBUG: TrayChild Accepted: Opera opera Opera
```