# Liferea invisible after trying to start it

Tags: laptop, dell, 11.10, liferea

Running latest Ubuntu on a Dell Laptop.
After clicking on Liferea icon on left-side Unity menu, icon starts to flash with background blinking in silver.
After a few minutes silver background stops flashing, becomes permanent, but no Liferea.

Ideas anyone?

Cheers/M

Comment: are you running the latest stable, or the latest unstable?  there's a difference: 11.10 is the unstable and is only in alpha, 11.04 is stable

Comment: See also:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/liferea/+bug/1186801

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Liferea is configured to "start in tray icon". You should check for a little earth icon in the top GNOME panel or the equivalent for Unity if it is different.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [whitelist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray/30748#30748) Liferea (as noted by @jmbouffard). If you don't know what term to add to the whitelist, take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/48281/1992).