# kget, Skype, and Vuze are not showing up in my panel

Tags: 11.04, unity

I have been having trouble with Unity. kGet, Skype and Vuze all give me the same problem. I can launch them once and after that if I close the Window I won't be able to get the application back. Killing the process and opening again is the way around I found. But I want to find if it's possible to fix it.

I don't even get the notification Icon for Vuze and Skype. How do I get them. If I get them I most probably be able to access the still running but hidden applications.

My `com.canonical.Unity.Panel` looks like this:

`['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service']`

Answer (score 3):

That is probably because in Natty the system tray is disabled by default. You can however "whitelist" applications. These applications will then show up in the top left corner of your screen right next to your other application indicators where they used to be.

To whitelist an application you can use dconf-tools.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Alt + F2 and type `dconf-editor`

Go to `com.canonical.Unity.Panel` (desktop -> unity -> panel) and change `systray-whitelist`.

Add the applications you want to whitelist. For example for skype add `, 'Skype'`.

Some information on how to debug this is here:

- [How do I know what to whitelist to allow my application into the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48281/how-do-i-know-what-to-whitelist-to-allow-my-application-into-the-system-tray)

**Edit:**

I got another idea. Try to add "notification area" to your panel. I was able to reproduce the same behaviour. Having Skype in the whitelist but the tray icon did not show up. It's probably because in your panel is only the "indicator applet complete" which has problems showing even whitelistet applications (using the classic desktop).

Comment: Well, Skype should be whitelisted by default though?

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. But as @jo-erlend said Skype is already whitelisted ~ Here is what it is - 
['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service']

Comment: I installed Stack Applet and it's showing in the notification area... But still no sign of Skype~

Comment: Stack Applet is an indicator , it has nothing to do with notification area and white-listing. Try re-installing Skype. And try to set the value to `['all']` and see what happens.

Comment: I wanted to ask how to add a notification area to my Panel? Not sure myself

Comment: Just right click the panel --> "Add to panel..." --> search for notification area and click "add".

Comment: @exasam he is using Unity, which does not use Gnome-panel or it's applets.