# Unity or Gnome 3. What's more stable to be used?

Tags: unity, gnome, skype

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 and I am still a newbee in Ubuntu. Ubuntu [gives me trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55000/applications-are-not-visible-ubuntu-11-04-unity) with Some Apps like - Skype, Vuzu and kGet. So I tried Gnome 2 but it's not much attractive. I wanted to know whether if Gnome 3 is much better or will installing Gnome 3 break Unity and make the system into a mess.

I want to have a stable yet attractive Ubuntu. So what's the best to do?

1. Install Gnome 3
2. Keep Unity and use alternate apps for Skype and others

Answer (score 2):

Up Until the next release of Ubuntu 11.10 Gnome 3 is not stable enough, and it breaks Unity in 11.04.

Unity is stable enough though to be used everyday.I don't know what problems you have with Skype, Vuze(?) and KGET as you didn't mentioned them.

What is best to do depends on what you want, if you want Unity use Unity, if you want to try Gnome Shell with the risk of breaking your system , then go ahead.

By the way, why don't you try to personalize Gnome 2 with some themes too.

Comment: Yeah... Sorry about that ~ This is the question~ (http://askubuntu.com/questions/55000/kget-skype-and-vuze-are-not-showing-up-in-my-panel)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the state of GNOME3 and is likely still the same (the recommendation is to wait until 11.10)

- [Gnome 3 ppa was unstable until April 28th, so is it ok now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37600/gnome-3-ppa-was-unstable-until-april-28th-so-is-it-ok-now/37804#37804)