# Working with printers in Ubuntu with the Unity desktop

Tags: unity, printing

How to I find my printer and stop print jobs that were not completed in Ubuntu with the Unity desktop?

Answer (score 3):

In 11.04, you can open system settings from the power-button in the upper-right corner. You'll find printers under Hardware and it'll display a list of printers. Double click it to show the queue.

In 11.10, we have a Printers item in the power-menu as a shortcut. The dialog itself has not changed.

Answer (score 2):

Search Unity for "Printing". You will find a list of your printers. If you double-click to open a selected printer, you can manage the print jobs including canceling jobs.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on "all" or the [appropriate value](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48281/how-do-i-know-what-to-whitelist-to-allow-my-application-into-the-system-tray) in the [whitelist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray) (for the system tray), you can see the print queue as normal.